# JavaFX File Chooser for an MVC Application

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

AFAIK, JavaFX doesn't have a **FileChooser** Component in Scene Builder/FXML. It is needed to set it using Java, using `javafx.stage.FileChooser` class. What is the best way to do it an MVC Application - where all my Views are in FXML?

Thanks.

Comment: fxml is only used to declare the UI. FileChooser is a ready-made component with its own UI. If for some reason you want to create FileChooser class objects by declaring in FXML just do not use Scene Builder

Comment: Could you give me an example of FileChooser in FXML? cc @mrmcwolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you give me an example of FileChooser in FXML? cc @mrmcwolf

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.stage.FileChooser?>

<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <fx:define>
        <FileChooser fx:id="chooser"/>
    </fx:define>

</GridPane>
```

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private FileChooser chooser;

}
```

By `fx:define` are declared objects that are not placed in the generated view but can be accessed in the controllers and / or in the other declarations via `id`.